# Сделать выборку

Tags: c#, sql

Помогите составить запрос.
Нужно получить перечень лекарств по указанной болезни.
Если кто не знает украинский:
Ліки - лекарства, хвороби - болезни.
СУБД access.
[image: Схема]

```
 OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Ліки, Призначення, Хвороби where Хвороби.Назва = 'Мигрень' and Ліки.Код = Призначення.Код_ліків and Хвороби.Код = Призначення.Код_хвороби ", sqlConnection1);

            sqlConnection1.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            лікиDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
            sqlConnection1.Close();
```

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, что Вы уже попробовали сделать с указанием того, что не получилось.

Comment: А что вы сами пытались сделать. Вообще берете все записи из таблицы лекарств с кодом лекарства из Призначення с нужной болезнью. На SQL пишеться практически так же как я сейчас словами сказал

Comment: "Select * from Ліки, Призначення, Хвороби where Хвороба.Назва=Мигрень and Ліки.Код = Призначення.Код_ліків and Хвороба.Код = Призначення.Код_хвороби " Пробовал так, но не вышло.

Comment: Это странно, выглядит запрос верно. Что значит "Не вышло"

Comment: Выбивает ошибку: Отсутствует значение для одного или нескольких требуемых параметров.

Comment: Может Мигрень надо было в кавычки взять (скорее всего одинарные) и вы СУБД не указали. проще всего было бы вбить в гугл название вашей базы и сообщение об ошибке. он бы сказал в чем причина. На вскидку это проблема не столько SQL, сколько того как вы параметры в запрос передаете и все ли переменные к этим параметрам привязываете

Comment: Ладно, спасибо. Попробую еще поискать.

Comment: Вы кстати уверены что можно писать названия полей/таблиц не английскими буквами, не заключая их в какие нибудь знаки вроде квадратных скобок, двойных или обратных кавычек. не знаю требования ацесса, но все остальные БД это требуют ...

Comment: Кстати, да. Щас попробую.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47821/discussion-between--and-mike).

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT
  t3.*
FROM
  [Хвороби] t1
  LEFT JOIN [Призначення] t2 ON (t1.[Код] = t2.[Код хвороби])
  JOIN [Ліки] t3 ON (t2.[Код ліків] = t3.[Код])
WHERE
  t1.Назва = 'qqq'
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN зачем ? Нам не требуется отбирать болезни от которых нет лекарств

Comment: @Mike Нам требуется отобрать лекарства по **указанной** болезни. Я предположил, что это значит, что известно ее название. Если для этой болезни нет лекарств, то и получим, как требовалось по условию, Empty Set

Comment: Если лекарств нет - то мы все равно получим из этой выборки одну строку где все поля будут NULL,  потому как в t3 таких записей нет, А LEFT заставит выдать запись даже если ее нет. Было бы логичней не получить ни одной строки

Comment: @Mike Логично. Но я привык к тому, что на болях кросс-таблиц стоят `NOT NULL` ограничения :) Хорошо. Отредактирую запрос

Comment: Это вы со старыми ораклами не работали, у которых все LEFT сносили крышу оптимизаторам и ими надо было очень аккуратно пользоваться :) А у ТС кстати запрос оказывается есть и похож на корректный, там собака где то в другом зарыта.

Comment: ... Приехали IS NOT NULL то зачем. Убираете перед JOIN слово LEFT и все происходит само собой, никаких доп проверок не нужно